# How can I append new/updated innerHTML to a p tag that doesn't have a class or id?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing out a test script where I'm wanting to select an existing p tag in a form and update the copy being used. I don't have access to the original code and having to use JavaScript only to make updates until it's approved by the client's tech lead and test results.

My original code is:

```
var p = document.querySelector(".form-bg form p").innerHTML;

p.innerHTML = 'By hitting Get Your Quote, I agree to receive autodialed calls, to include scheduling reminders, and texts from this company.';
```

However, the p tag's content isn't being updated and hitting barriers stating the code is undefined or isn't a function.

So, I attempted using .appendChild() with a thought process of creating a new element and hiding the existing if I can't update the existing copy.

My updated code using .appendChild() is:

```
let updatedCopy = document.createElement('p');

updatedCopy.id = 'testCopy';

updatedCopy.innerHTML = 'By hitting Get Your Quote, I agree to receive autodialed calls, to include scheduling reminders, and texts from this company';

document.getElementsByClassName('form-bg').appendChild(updatedCopy);
```

I've tried running this within the browser, but haven't been successful yet. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! :)

Lastly, here's the HTML snippet with the form that's needing to be modified:

```
<div id="lightbox_shell">
    <div class="test-w_contact-lightbox-individuals">
        <div class="form-main-bg">
            <div class="close-bg">
                <button class="close" type="button">close</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Form Starts Here -->
            <div class="form-bg">
                <div class="legend">
                    Provide your information so an agent can reach you.
                </div>
                <form method="post">
                    <input name="offering" type="hidden" value="Individual"> <input name="language" type="hidden" value="English">
                    <div class="contact-fields">
                        <div class="flex_columns">
                            <div class="flex_2col">
                                <span class="input-text firstname" data-manual="1"><input class="required" id="firstname" maxlength="150" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name *" title="First Name" type="text"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_2col">
                                <span class="input-text lastname" data-manual="1"><input class="required" id="lastname" maxlength="150" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name *" title="Last Name" type="text"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex_columns">
                            <div class="flex_2col">
                                <span class="input-text phone" data-manual="1"><input class="required" id="phone" maxlength="12" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number *" title="Phone Number" type="tel"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_2col">
                                <span class="input-text zipcode" data-manual="1"><input class="required" id="zipcode" maxlength="5" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code *" title="Zip Code" type="tel"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex_columns">
                            <div class="flex_2col">
                                <span class="input-text email" data-manual="1"><input class="required" id="email" maxlength="255" name="email" placeholder="Email *" title="Email" type="email"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex_2col">
                                <div class="requirement-info">
                                    * fields are required
                                </div>
                                <ul class="misc">
                                    <li>
                                        <p>Would you like an agent to call asap?</p><label class="checkbox"><input name="yesmeet" type="checkbox"> Yes</label> <label class="checkbox"><input name="nomeet" type="checkbox"> No</label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p style="font-size: 13px;line-height: 100%;margin: 15px 0 14px;">By hitting submit, I agree to receive autodialed calls, to include scheduling reminders, and texts from this company.</p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="raq-complete-panel">
                <div class="thanks">
                    <div class="title">
                        Thank You!
                    </div>
                    <p>An agent will call you<br>
                    <span class="eta">within 15 minutes.</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <p>Your confirmation number is <span class="number"></span>.</p>
                    <p>If you have any questions regarding your request, contact us at <a class="textlink" href="mailto:email@test.com">email@test.com</a></p>
                    <p>Please provide your confirmation number listed above for reference.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfloat"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, not a single element. Pick the first found element using `[0]`, or use `querySelector(`form-bg`)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first try was so close. You want your assignment to be like this:

```
var p = document.querySelector(".form-bg form > p");
```

then you can set the `innerHTML`.

```
p.innerHTML = "Your new text";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I updated the code and realized that the .form-bg form p is pulling a different p tag than the one I'm targeting so it looks like I'll have to be more specific. It's grabbing the "Would you like an agent to call asap?" p tag and not the "By hitting submit, I agree to receive autodialed calls, to include scheduling reminders, and texts from this company." p tag.  Added [1] before .innerHTML to see if that would help indicate which p tag I'd like to select and received an error message of "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined".

Comment: @Alysia you can use `.form-bg form > p` to get only direct descendants of the `form` element.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much @Brandon :)